# How to specify Views page as parent for menu link?

Tags: views, 8, navigation

I have a module with a menu link which I want to appear as a child of another link in the admin menu. The would-be-parent link is to a Views page if that matters.

This is the contents of mymodule.links.menu.yml:

```
mymodule.add_location:
  route_name: mymodule.add_form
  parent: views.branch_locations.page
  description: 'Add a foo.'
  title: Add new
  menu_name: admin
```

I got the `views.branch_locations.page` machine name for the desired parent link from [`ViewsMenuLink::getDerivativeDefinitions()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21views%21src%21Plugin%21Derivative%21ViewsMenuLink.php/function/ViewsMenuLink%3A%3AgetDerivativeDefinitions/8.4.x), the class responsible for dynamically providing menu links for the Views module.

With the current setup the "Add new" item doesn't appear under "Branch Locations" in the admin menu. The `route_name` definitely exists, and no error is thrown when clearing cache or rebuilding menus, which suggests Drupal is accepting `views.branch_locations.page` as a valid parent link somewhere along the line.

But how do I get this item to show up in the menu, as a sub-item of the specified `parent`? I guess I could use the API to programatically create the link, although I haven't tried it so it might have the same problem, but I want this one in config.

Is the problem maybe that because the Views module declares its links dynamically, I need to do the same for that dynamically created parent to even be available?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Views generates menu link id's with a prefix `views_view:` and the first page display normally has the id `page_1`, so the parent should be something like this:

```
  parent: views_view:views.branch_locations.page_1
```

There is no error thrown, if `parent:` doesn't match an existing menu link. It's ignored and the menu link appears in the top level of the menu.

It doesn't matter from which provider the menu links are from, all discovered menu links are treated equally in the menu tree table.